# Output data from database only if current field is not empty?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a little problem here:
I want to only output things, if there are entries in the database table. Right now my code looks like this:

```
foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    if ($customer->CURRENT_ROWNAME != NULL) {
    //output stuff e.g.
    <p>ID: {{$customer->customer_id}}</p>
    <p>E-Mail: {{$customer->email}}</p>
    <p>Phone: {{$customer->phone}}</p>
    <p>Mobile: {{$customer->mobile}}</p>
    else {
    //do not output stuff
    }
}
```

I THOUGHT I should search for something that outputs the name of the current field, so that it skips empty entries, like, if there is no mobile number in the table, then do not output that. So my logic is flawed right from the start. That lead me to a rather unbeautiful "solution":

```
@foreach ($customers as $customer)
    <h2>{{$customer->name}} | {{$customer->company}}</h2>
    <div class="column-left">
        <p>ID: {{$customer->customer_id}}</p>
        <p>E-Mail: {{$customer->email}}</p>
        <p>Phone: {{$customer->phone}}</p>
    @if($customer->mobile != NULL)
        <p>Mobile: {{$customer->mobile}}</p>
    @else
    @endif
    </div>
@endforeach
```

So this does work. But theoretically, I would need to do this manually to every database entry, where I am not exactly sure, if that field could be blank or not.

Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: Your query should be optimized to give only the wanted results. Your code should not filter anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#example-5891):

```
<?php
$data = array(
             0 => array(
                'name'=> '',
                'company'=>'companyName',
                'customer_id'=> 123456,
                'phone'=> '11111',
            ),
             1 => array(
                'name'=> 'Tom',
                'company'=>'',
                'customer_id'=> 123457,
                'phone'=> '11112',
            ),
             2 => array(
                'name'=> 'Daniel',
                'company'=>'companyName',
                'customer_id'=> '',
                'phone'=> '11113',
            ),
             3 => array(
                'name'=> 'Bob',
                'company'=>'companyName',
                'customer_id'=> 123458,
                'phone'=> '',
            ),
             4 => array(
                'name'=> 'Amy',
                'company'=>'companyName',
                'customer_id'=> '123456',
                'phone'=> '11114',
            ),
          );
$customers = array();
foreach ($data as $value) {
    array_push($customers,array_filter( $value));
}
print_r($customers);
return $customers;
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [company] => companyName
            [customer_id] => 123456
            [phone] => 11111
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Tom
            [customer_id] => 123457
            [phone] => 11112
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Daniel
            [company] => companyName
            [phone] => 11113
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Bob
            [company] => companyName
            [customer_id] => 123458
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Amy
            [company] => companyName
            [customer_id] => 123456
            [phone] => 11114
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

On the customers model you could put the logic in there so example;

```
public function hasMobile() {
    if($this->mobile){
        return '<p>Mobile: ' . $this->mobile . '</p>';
    }

    return null;
}
```

Do that for each item you want to show/not show then in your view you can reference that each time rather than having the if statement all over the place in x amount of views. It would also be good if you needed to update it, update one they would all change

View would be like;

```
    {{ $customer->hasMobile() }}
```

There is most likely a better way but this is the option I would go for.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm quite new to Laravel, I'm at chapter 6 of "Laravel from Scratch" from the official website. I wanted to try things out and see how it goes. Your solution makes alot more sense, but where would I put that function in? Which file? I Have no customer "model" or something (yet?)

Comment: When you pull information from a database in laravel you will have a model to allow you to get the data, you would have had to run a migration to create the database?